# "iwconfig" cannot be found, cannot install wireless-tools

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm a beginner when it comes to using the Ubuntu terminal, so this might be a mistake that I'm drastically overthinking. 
So my problem is kind of paradoxical. I need to connect to the internet, but the iwconfig command does not work because I have not downloaded the wireless-tools. However, when I try to download the wireless tools, I cannot do so because of a connection failure. 
I tried to update Ubuntu but it failed because of a connection failure. I have tried everything I could find on the internet and still could not find a solution. 
Where do I start?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I would start by connecting an ethernet cable and use that until you have all you need to use wireless. Providing us with actual error messages and as much detail as possible is also helpful (release of Ubuntu?  can you ping your router? ping outside (eg. 8.8.8.8 for google dns), ping a named address (google.com) provide clues as to issue. If you don't have ethernet, you may find them on your install media (*I'd want to know your release to be certain but you didn't provide it*); or download them on a different pc & walk them to your machine...

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the internet with wire...

Two best options

1. Kinko's has laptop stations you can connect to with a wire port
2. Home PC buy a reliable usb donge from amazon that works with no driver needed..

Best advice I can give with limited resources.